# How to process multiple scanner input lines

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

How do I use multiple scanners input at one time? (Example: I am doing program in which there is printed: radius, circumference, diameter and area, each value on its line.
And the user inputs one of this values. And then the program using that one value prints the rest) 
I don't know how to separate the inputs

Comment: And why do u need multiple scanner at the same time for that? You read the value once anyway, then just manipulate it appropriately.

Comment: All that can be achieved by using *only one* scanner.

Comment: You don't need to. If the input is an user prompt, the only Scanner you need is one reading your program's standard input (System.in), on which the user will provide all the required values (separated by space, linefeed or what you'd like). You will however call the scanner's methods multiple times to ask for multiple data.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use multiple `Scanner`s because they consume a stream and having more than one object of them may lead to side effects. here is more about that: https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/java/FIO06-J.+Do+not+create+multiple+buffered+wrappers+on+a+single+byte+or+character+stream

But what you could do is reading line-by-line (and for your use case you do not need more than one canner, you could also read one line and separate the values by semicoln or whitespace etc.):

```
private void readInput() {
  int radius, circum, ...
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter radius:")
  radius = sc.nextDouble();
  //do so with your other variables  
}
```